# Is there a way to filter by sessions in Google Analytics custom dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, session

I'm trying to configure a widget to get pageviews/session and conversion rates by browser. Unfortunately, it's ordered by pageviews. Thus, I end up with unrelevant data because some browsers have high pageviews/session but with only a few sessions.

I'd like to filter the results by sessions to display only browsers that total at least 500 sessions or so.

Is there a way to do that or displaying and ordering by sessions instead of pageviews/session is the only way to go?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know it is only possible by also displaying sessions in the widget unfortunately.

Comment: I found that the only solution apart from ordering by session is to filter to only display relevent browsers.